# How can I safely share Rails configuration with Ember.js?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ember.js, devise

I'm building a rails-backed ember.js application. My main application.hbs file has a "logout" link in there and I want to make this link use the :delete method (I'm using devise to handle authentication). What I can't decide is how to output a link from a rails route. I've got all my *ember* routes defined in javascript, but how can I get the delete URL into handlebars?

```
= link_to 'Logout', app.destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete
```

I'd like to pass in some configuration options (urls and the like) from Rails into my Ember.Application instatiation:

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create()
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the information is safe in the public's hands, you can always pop that sort of thing into a meta tag as a JSON string. You can also just make available a global config object that can be called from whatever child scope in the app you need. For example:

```
<meta name="rails-config" content="<%= @rails_config %>" />
```

`@rails_config` can obviously be set from the controller. You can snag that with jQuery using `JSON.parse($('meta[name="rails-config"]').attr('content'))` from wherever you want to initialize and store it in your ember app.

Or, just a good old fashioned global variable:

```
window.GLOBAL_RAILS_SETTINGS = {
  foo: '<%= Settings.foo %>',
  bar: '<%= Settings.bar %>',
  baz: '<%= @baz %>',
};
```

As you can see, I've also pulled in some stuff from the settings.yml (or whatever environment) file.

Hope that helps! You can store your logout url as a string and then just use a regular anchor tag or a `{{link-to}}` helper in your handlebars. No need to get fancy for this use-case, it seems.

There are bound to be other ways to do this. I don't know if there really is a "right" way, other than to just caution to not expose sensitive data.